# Flag declined on a question re: reviewers that accepted a bad (IMO) edit

Tags: discussion, flags

I raised a flag a while ago, re: revision 2 of a not-great question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39264287/revisions where a questionable edit from a low-rep user (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20783096) was accepted.

I wanted moderators to give the reviewers a slap on the wrist for accepting an edit that changed the question to be about x86, instead of whatever architecture it was originally about, and made a mess of the question. (Pushing the last two parts of the original way down below a big wall of x86 implicit-addressing-mode examples with way too much detail).  Notice that the edit deletes the `CLA`,`CME`,`INP` instructions and replaces them with x86 `SAHF`,`LAHF`, and `CPUID`.

I don't know exactly when it was declined; I don't check my flags page often and there's no notification.

> An edit was approved that changes the question from talking about some unspecified accumulator architecture to talking about x86. At least one answerer seems to know what the question is talking about, and got more upvotes than my correct answer with x86 examples, so turning this into an x86 question is inappropriate. Also, most of the edit would work better as an answer, or maybe a separate section to the question. **I'll fix the question, but please deal with the reviewers.**
>
> – Peter Cordes Sep 6 at 1:46
>
> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

The bolded part was of course not bolded originally. I probably should have put it first, because it seems that the mod thought I wanted them to do something about the edit itself.

As I said in the flag message, *I* fixed the question (with a re-edit that introduced some of the added example).

I'd already answered the question a while ago (basically disputing the premise that a whole instruction must fall into one category: rather each operand can be implicit or explicit, and possibly immediate, and some instructions have both). That's definitely true for x86, so turning it into an x86 question makes the more-popular answers less correct.

Apparently people searching for this question did find the simplistic answers other than mine useful, so this was definitely a bad edit.

---

I'm posting here instead of raising another flag so I have space to explain everything. I fully understand that moderators have to skim to get through flags quickly, because fast with high accuracy is better than slow with perfect accuracy. Mistakes can be fixed, and this is one of those cases.

---

- **Was I correct to raise that flag in the first place?**
- **How should I have explained myself more clearly in the original flag?** for the benefit of busy moderators.

Comment: I would have added a link to the review so it is more obvious that the review is the problem. You rambling in a flag about x86 is not going to be understood by most mods.

Comment: @rene: so in the limited space of a flag, leave out (most of?) the explanation of why it was a bad edit, in favour of a link to the review?  Are mods prepared to take the word of an asm gold badge holder on that?  Cody Gray is a moderator, and was active in x86 / asm tags before becoming one (and a bit afterwards).  I'm pretty confident he'd understand the question and my explanation.  I didn't need the flag handled in a hurry, and I thought it was important to justify my argument.  (Since I think you need to understand asm to know what to say to the reviewers.)

Comment: Yes, you could have said: my edit will show how bad that suggested edit was and why its reviewers need to be investigated. That should be the focus of your flag and atm it isn't, IMO. And Cody hasn't been on for a while now, nor do you have a guarantee that he will handle your flag. You don't need to explain to a mod how awesome you are. You need them to investigate the reviewing actions of the reviewers as you believe they are wrong.

Comment: @rene: That makes sense.  Looking at the timestamps, I edited ~9 minutes after raising the flag, so I hadn't actually done that yet when I flagged.  It would have made sense to do that first, so I could refer to it in the flag.  (And also to make sure the edit was as bad as I thought before flagging, in case I noticed something while editing.)

Comment: Yeah, it is tricky these kind of cases but they don't need a speedy delivery (like spam or rude flags) so you can better take enough time to make sure both the context and the flag are clear so a mod will look into the behavior / actions and not be distracted by possible needed domain knowledge. But I give you those are not easy flags.

Comment: @rene: Thinking back, I think my verbose explanation of the problem *was* to try to help the mods out by providing the domain knowledge.  I should correct my earlier comment: I was hoping Cody would handle the flag, but tried to write it so a mod with less asm knowledge could handle it.  (And it probably partially turned into explaining how awesome I am; that tends to happen for me, but hey at least it's true a decent amount of the time :P)

Comment: FWIW, based on a bit of Googling, I'm pretty sure that "whatever architecture it was originally about" is the "[Mano machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mano_machine)", described (under the unfortunately generic title "basic computer") by M. Morris Mano in their 1993 textbook _Computer System Architecture_. We even have [a tag for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mano-machine), although it seems sadly underused, probably because most students asking questions about the architecture don't know it by that name.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm the moderator that declined this. Looking at the time line, I did so on the 18th (about a week and a half after you raised the issue).

Unfortunately, I can't remember why I declined it. The text looks vaguely familiar and the explanation in your flag is clear (as is this meta post).

I'm sorry about that declined flag.

To directly answer your questions:

1. Yes you were correct to raise the flag. Please continue to do so.
2. I can't tell you what I was thinking on the 18th, but rereading the flag now, it seems pretty clear what you are asking about.